# Publishing MVC 3 app to IIS 6 via filesystem. Files still refer to dev environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am publishing the mvc3 project to the qa environment via the filesystem/network share using the publish command.  When I attempt to run the program I get the following error:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length]
 System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) +9384283
 System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) +11
 MyProject.Controllers.LoginController.validateUser() in **C:\DEVPATH\Controllers\LoginController.cs**:42
 MyProject.Controllers.LoginController.Index() in **C:\DEVPATH\Controllers\LoginController.cs**:15
```

This is the path I have in development, I have searched for hardcoded paths but they return nothing.

The path where the deployment package is D:\QAPATH... yet when there is an error it shows the dev path C:\DEVPATH.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problems with publishing, your problem is in `LoginController.validateUser()` method: it passes negative substring length value to `String.Substring` function.

Comment: It works in the development environment and I find it strange that it is referencing my development path from the qa environment.  Is this normal?

Comment: @SpencerRoberts The path shown is metadata in the symbol files.  It's based on where you build the binaries (e.g. if built on someone else's machine, they'd get a different file path but same line number).

Comment: I built the package in development and copied it to qa, then when I get errors it is referring to my dev box.  I'm not sure how to build in qa without installing visual studio and I don't have permission to do that.  In non mvc development I don't have this issue.